# How to fill values between matching values, but not between non-matching values, in one column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Using this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x= c(NA,1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA, 3, NA), 
time = c(1:15))
```

I want to fill in the values for x between values of x that match, but I do not want to fill in values between where x does not match. This is over a time course, so I cannot just remove all NA values to get this result.
The previous data frame would ideally be filled as:

```
x = c(NA,1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 3, 3, 3, NA)
```

I tried using tidyr 'fill', but that fills in the unwanted NA spots.

Answer (score 1):

a bit verbose but you can do this with `tidyr::fill`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(x_up=x,
         x_down=x) %>%
  fill(x_up,.direction="up")%>%
  fill(x_down,.direction="down") %>%
  mutate(x=if_else(x_up==x_down,x_up,x))

    x time x_up x_down
1  NA    1    1     NA
2   1    2    1      1
3   1    3    1      1
4   1    4    1      1
5   1    5    1      1
6  NA    6    2      1
7   2    7    2      2
8   2    8    2      2
9   2    9    2      2
10  2   10    2      2
11 NA   11    3      2
12  3   12    3      3
13  3   13    3      3
14  3   14    3      3
15 NA   15   NA      3
```